# How is it possible to make json query client side

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i want to make a jsonQuery client-side. like this:

```
 var jsonQuery = require('json-query');

jsonQuery('routes[start=London].end', {
    data: $scope.stations
});
```

I got the error that 'requireis not defined'. 
How is it possible to make querys client side?

thx in advance!

Comment: It seems you're trying to run nodejs package in browser. Take a look into js module bundlers such as `webpack` or `browserify`. They will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I am using asp.net and tired to install requirejs. after that i get the error:  Error: Module name "routes[start=Augsburg].end" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]). How is the right syntax for that?